# B-cell and T-cell activation by parasites

Tags: immunology, parasitology

Parasitic infections lead to the production of parasite-specific IgE, but they also lead to the activation of nonspecific, polyclonal B-cells and T-cells. How do parasites trigger non-specific activation?

Answer (score 2):

I've found a great [article](http://www.pasteur.fr/recherche/unites/tcruzi/minoprio/Int_parasitol.pdf) that says:

> Mitogens   and   superantigens   have   been   described   to
>   explain the strategy used by microorganisms to avoid the
>   host specifc immune responses and to ensure persistence.
>   These  moieties  are  responsible  for  the  initiation  of  non-
>   specifc  (polyclonal)  immune  responses.

Mitogens are chemicals (usually proteins) that promote mitosis. Superantigens (sAg) form a subclass of antigens and are capable of inducing massive polyclonal T-cell activation and cytokine release (Cytokines crucial role in immune system mediation). Their ability to inflict massive T-cell activation comes from the fact that they bind directly to MHC-II without any pre-processing, and stimulate T-cell activation.
Source: https://escholarship.org/uc/item/47g8w51m
Also there are B-cell sAgs that stimulate B-cells, and their activation.

These altogether (mitogens cytokines, sAgs) result in rapid expansion of B-cells and T-cells.

Also [this](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/jpr/2012/362131/) paper might help to understand why parasites trigger polyclonal T and B-cell activation. Namely to avoid host specific immune system, dilute the pathogen specific anti-bodies. It is important to note that chronic infections could lead to several auto-immune diseases.

Comment: Maybe we should attack the superantigens if they are so strong virulence factors, instead of developing antibiotics, which don't work.

Comment: Yepp, there is some research in the topic: http://www.mdpi.com/2072-6651/6/6/1724/htm http://informahealthcare.com/doi/abs/10.1517/14728222.2012.682573
Btw. afaik. superantigens are a subgroup of mitogens.

Comment: @inf3rno -  Well mitogen is a broad term, so I guess you can view it as such.